# How to ignore folder to upload to Git?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using `Laravel` project with `AWS` the way that I upload the project is by `codecommit` and `codepipeline` to aws so I have folder in public directory called `uploads` I need when I upload the changes that I made then upload to aws ignore the `uploads` folder.

in my `.gitignore` file:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/uploads
```

But when I upload the changes in project the folder is uploaded even I put in `.gitignore` to do not upload this!

the commands that I upload:

```
 git add .
 git commit -m ‘test’
 git push
```

How can I ignore the folder ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the trailing `/` of the folders? E.g, `node_modules` instead of `/node_modules`?

Comment: I would start with removing the root '/' as well. The first slash mean root of the filesystem, which will probably not match anything in your repository unless you checkout to '/' of your filesystem, which I discourage you from doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this instead:

```
node_modules/
public/hot/
public/uploads/
```

Answer (score 1):

just a Tip

On Windows and Mac, if you want to ignore a folder named Flower_Data_Folder in the current directory, you can do:

```
echo Flower_Data_Folder >> .gitignore
```

If it's a file named `data.txt`:

```
echo data.txt >> .gitignore
```

If it's a path like "Data/passwords.txt"

```
echo "Data/passwords.txt" >> .gitignore.
```

so since you want to exclude folders one by one run the commands like for e.g to exclude `node_module`

`echo node_modules >> .gitignore`